# Can i set and use the variable in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I can try the this function but i can't setting edit row how to solve this problem.if i can use row.original problem is solved but i curiosity how to use with editrow

```
const handleDeleteRow = async (row) => {
    console.log(row.original);
    setEditRow(row.original);
    console.log(editRow);

    if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${editRow.name}`)) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.delete(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/Airline/DeleteAsync`, { data: editRow });

        if (res.status === 200) {
          const index = tableData.findIndex(x => x.id === editRow.id);
          setTableData([...tableData.slice(0, index), ...tableData.slice(index + 1)]);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

I can try the this function but i can't setting edit row how to solve this problem.if i can use row.original problem is solved but i curiosity how to use with editrow

Answer (score -1):

When using `useState` hook, the state would be updated only during the next render. This is explained in [the react docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value):

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

function handleClick() {
  console.log(count);  // 0

  setCount(count + 1); // Request a re-render with 1
  console.log(count);  // Still 0!

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(count); // Also 0!
  }, 5000);
}

return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
```

There is no good workaround but to save your new state into a variable and use it in the callback:

```
const newEditRow = row.original;
setEditRow(newEditRow);

if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${newEditRow.name}`)) {
  // ...
}
```